# How to place switch statement into javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am busy with making an nifty tool that measures click for heart beat(s) and then after then clicks it will tell you endUsers Average Heart Rate.

It works fine, when the 10 clicks are over, it will consider my array and calculate an average and alert(); the user with the average.

What I want to do now is instead of alerting the endUser with their average heart rate, alerting them with a diagnosis. So when average equals a value below 59, it should alert("Your heart is effective and fit"); and if it is above 100 it should alert("Your heart is not effective.."); you get the point.

**My problem**: I can't seem to figure our where to place the switch statement for this, because the error will either tell me: Can't find the variable (that I want to use in the switch statement) or when I place the switch statement somewhere else, it alerts the user with the default-case..

**Should I even be using**

> av = average /= count;

**for my switch statement? All I want it to do is, give out alerts based on the case which is all based on the value of the average.**

**my codes**:

The normal working code without switch statement:

```
<script>
  var lastTapSeconds = 0;
  var bpm = 0;

  //extra variabelen voor functionaliteit uitbreiding.
  var beats = [];
  var average = 0;
  var count = 0;

  var tapDiv = document.getElementById("tapDiv");

  $(tapDiv).on('click', function() {
    var tapSeconds = new Date().getTime();

    bpm = ((1 / ((tapSeconds - lastTapSeconds) / 1000)) * 60);
    lastTapSeconds = tapSeconds;
    tapDiv.innerHTML = '<h1 style="display:inline;">' + Math.floor(bpm) + '</h1><img style="height:256px;width:256px;" src="img/heart.png"/>';

    //extra functionaliteit
    beats.push(Math.floor(bpm));
    average *= count;  //average = average * count
    average += Math.floor(bpm);  //average = average + count
    count++;
    average /= count;  //average = average / counterIncrement


    //als array entries 10 heeft bereikt geef prompt met gemiddelde bpm.
    if(beats.length >= 10) {
      alert("Your Average Beats Per Minute: " + average);
    }
  });
</script>
```

**The updated code**:

```
 <script>
  var lastTapSeconds = 0;
  var bpm = 0;

  //extra variabelen voor functionaliteit uitbreiding.
  var beats = [];
  var average = 0;
  var count = 0;

  var tapDiv = document.getElementById("tapDiv");

  $(tapDiv).on('click', function() {
    var tapSeconds = new Date().getTime();

    bpm = ((1 / ((tapSeconds - lastTapSeconds) / 1000)) * 60);
    lastTapSeconds = tapSeconds;
    tapDiv.innerHTML = '<h1 style="display:inline;">' + Math.floor(bpm) + '</h1><img style="height:256px;width:256px;" src="img/heart.png"/>';

  //extra functionaliteit
  beats.push(Math.floor(bpm));
  average *= count;  //average = average * count
  average += Math.floor(bpm);  //average = average + count
  count++;
  average /= count;  //average = average / counterIncrement


  //als array entries 10 heeft bereikt geef prompt met gemiddelde bpm.
  if(beats.length >= 10) {
  //alert("Your Average Beats Per Minute: " + average);


  var av = average /= count;


  switch(av) {

    case (average>60 && avarage<100):
    alert("From the measurements, we conclude that you have a normal resting heart rate.");
    break;


    case (average<59):
    alert("From the measurements, we conclude that you have an efficient heart function and better cardiovascular fitness.");
    break;

    case (average>100):
    alert("From the measurements, we conclude that your resting heart has an high average, we might be stated as unefficient and not fit.");
    break;

    default:
    alert("Please measure again, your measurements seem unregular.");
    break;

  }
  var bpm = 0;
  var average = 0;
}
});
```

Comment: try to use "if" instead of "switch"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: `switch(av) { case (average>60 && avarage<100):` - youre passing in `av` but then using `average` and `avarage`

Comment: very low content, with a lot of errors as sayed @Craicerjack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use multiple `if-else` statements:

```
if ( average > 60 && average < 100 )
    alert( "From the measurements, we conclude that you have a normal resting heart rate." );
else if ( average < 59 )
    alert( "From the measurements, we conclude that you have an efficient heart function and better cardiovascular fitness." );
else if ( average > 100 )
    alert( "From the measurements, we conclude that your resting heart has an high average, we might be stated as unefficient and not fit." );
else
    alert( "Please measure again, your measurements seem unregular." );
```

The problem in your code is that values in `case` are calculated in run time and became equal `true` or `false`. So every time `default` section should be executed

Comment: It's normal to check for boundaries in order, so you don't need to check 2 boundary conditions in your first statement. Additionally, with the conditions as written, you're missing the range [59,60].

Comment: Wauw, how stupid am I.. thank you very much, I truly have learned :)

Answer (score 0):

Your switch is wrong. You should read up on using the switch. Each case: part should have one possible value for the variable av. Not a conditional. In your case, for example, av is checked against (average > 60 && average < 100), which is either true or false. So unless av itself is true or false, your switch doesn't make sense.

You should solve this using regular if-statement. It can't be done with a switch.